# versioning best practices for ruby gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, version-control, rubygems, versioning

I'm adding new gems and functionality to it often. Before my last release some of my code broke in my dev environment and I found out it was because some of my gems (CarrierWave and jQuery in particular) had been updated and didn't work with some code.

What's the best way to manage gems regarding versioning? Some seem to say that you should always specify the version number in your Gemfile...but for all gems? Just some?

I know that for some gems you may *have* to store the version numbers because of bugs, etc. But these aside, in development there are times where I'm adding new gems and may need to do a `bundle update` to get the new stuff working but then don't want to break old stuff.

I have good tests to hopefully catch a lot of errors before pushing to production. How are other users ensuring gem update may not break completely unrelated functionality when in development?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you dont' want you app to break because of backward-incompatible gem updates, you do have to specify gem versions. What I found to be a good practice is using the pessimistic operator `~>` to specify gem versions. For example:

```
gem carrierwave, '~>0.6.0'
```

This means the carrierwave gem will be frozen at version 0.6, but bundle will install any minor, backward-compatible updates and bug fixes, which are usually increments of the last number (0.6.1, 0.6.2...). That means you can update your bundle without running the risk of breaking something (no more flinching when running `bundle update`).

You can also use the pessimistic operator on major versions:

```
gem devise, '~>2.0'
```

Meaning bundle will update to versions 2.1.0, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.3.0, but never to 3.x.

Some considerations:

1. You don't **have** to specify all gem versions, but it's good practice. I don't specify versions of my own gems, for example. But every third party gem has its version specified. Otherwise, I'd be trusting my code to things beyond my control.
2. You still need to have a certain amount of trust in the gem maintainers to use the pessimistic operator. A reckless maintainer still could release backwards-incompatible changes in a minor version. In those cases, I lock the minor version (no pessimistic operator).
3. If you specify gem versions, you'll be making bundle's work of resolving gem dependencies a lot easier, meaning it'll do it much faster.

Comment: awesome, thanks Andre. this is as i suspected. so, should I run `bundle show` and get my current versions from here then augment my Gemfile? or is there another command that shows the gem versions i should use better?

Comment: I usually check the versions in my `Gemfile.lock`. But `bundle show` also works fine.

Comment: I recently took over an app which is in production pulling one of its gem from a git repo, I just think this is crazy, as most of the specs are now not running locally in my development machine because the head for that repo has too many differences, any best practices/patterns on why I shouldn't use git repos for production stuff?